Stacked and Grouped Column Chart in R using Highcharts
I am trying to create a column chart in R using the Highcharts, in which I want my columns to be grouped and stacked on different features. Here is my sample data table.



Zone
Revenue Type
TTM2
TTM1




Americas
SaaS
901
1001


Americas
Subscriptions
902
1002


Americas
Perpetual Maintenance
903
1003


Americas
Perpetual
904
1004


APAC
SaaS
905
1005


APAC
Subscriptions
906
1006


APAC
Perpetual Maintenance
907
1007


APAC
Perpetual
908
1008


EMEA
SaaS
909
1009


EMEA
Subscriptions
910
1010


EMEA
Perpetual Maintenance
911
1011


EMEA
Perpetual
912
1012



I want my column chart to have Zone on x-axis where each column will represent TTM2 and TTM1. And each of these columns should be stacked based on Revenue Type.
To make it more complicated, I want stacking to be done based on percentage of that Revenue Type share, while column height to still show the actual numeric sum. And after that something which can show the percentage change between the two columns of same group (Zone).
Here is an screenshot how it should look at the end

So, far I tried various ways but none really worked. The closest I could reach is following -
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table::data.table(
  Zone = c("Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "Americas", "APAC", "APAC", "APAC", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA"),
  Revenue_Type = c("SaaS", "Subscriptions", "Perpetual Maintenance", "Perpetual", "SaaS", "Subscriptions", "Perpetual Maintenance", "Perpetual", "SaaS", "Subscriptions", "Perpetual Maintenance", "Perpetual"),
  TTM2 = c(901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912),
  TTM1 = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012)
)

dt <- data.table::melt(dt, id.vars = c("Zone", "Revenue_Type"), measure.vars = c("TTM1", "TTM2"), variable.name = "TTM", variable.factor = FALSE, value.name = "value")

# Create a Highchart object
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = unique(dt$Zone)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Value")) %>%
  # Add the data series for TTM1
  hc_add_series(
    data = dt[TTM == "TTM1"],
    type = "column",
    hcaes(x = Zone, y = value, group = Revenue_Type),
    stacking = "normal"
  ) %>%
  # Add the data series for TTM2
  hc_add_series(
    data = dt[TTM == "TTM2"],
    type = "column",
    hcaes(x = Zone, y = value, group = Revenue_Type),
    stacking = "normal"
  )

But it stacks my both grouped columns onto each other, neither I am figure how the way to show percentage while keeping the column height as numeric sum. That's how it looks -


There are quite a few examples that achieve what you are trying to get. Such as, https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m36acyx8 , https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kmnq3tv0/ .  But I am not sure how to implement them into R. Are you open to using ggplot2 package or you want to use highcharter only?

Thanks, The first example was really helpful and I was able to implement the same into R and it worked quite well. Now I have a few things pending in this if you can also help get around those. 1- How do I also show the stack name under each column (above category names)? 2- How to adjust the height of individual stacks within a column based on their percentage but keeping the total height of the column unchanged? Thanks!

If you share the R code I can look into it. Seems like there would be two layers of axis values. I am not sure but try stacking = "percentage".

Here is the R code -
`series_ttm2 <- lapply(unique(dt$Revenue_Type), function(rt) {list(name = rt,data = dt[Revenue_Type == rt, TTM2],stack = "TTM2",id = rt)})
series_ttm1 <- lapply(unique(dt$Revenue_Type), function(rt) {list(name = rt,data = dt[Revenue_Type == rt, TTM1],stack = "TTM1",linkedTo = rt)})
series <- c(series_ttm2, series_ttm1)
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
hc_xAxis(categories = unique(dt$Zone)) %>%
hc_add_series_list(series)`

Also, I already tried stacking = 'percent' but problem is that it also re-adjusts height of each column to 100. while I want column height to remain unchanged to show the actual absolute sum.
